# Free public interest data hosting?

Tags: dataset

I have hourly and daily temperature reports for many stations at 
http://data.barrycarter.info/

I encourage people to download it, but, at 6.6G, it uses up a lot of 
bandwidth.

Is there a service that hosts "public interest" data for free?

I know about http://aws.amazon.com/publicdatasets, but you need an 
Amazon EC2 account to access that data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did a quick search for google projects that may fit your needs, and I came up with two hits, which I have not tested:
[Google Fusion Tables](https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLogin?service=fusiontables&passive=1209600&continue=http://www.google.com/fusiontables/Home&followup=http://www.google.com/fusiontables/Home) and [Google Public Data](http://www.google.com/publicdata/admin)

Comment: I knew about Google Fusion Tables from Google Maps' API, but didn't realize there was a free standalone version. Thanks!

Comment: Turns out Fusion Tables are limited to 100M/table and 250M/user, and my data's a lot bigger than that. Checking out Google Public Data now.

Answer (score 5):

How about the [UCI Machine Learning Repository](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/index.html)? Here is their [data donation policy](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/donation_policy.html).

Answer (score 2):

You should also take a look at [Infochimps](http://www.infochimps.com/).  I've never used the site personally, but it's designed for precisely this.

Comment: They don't host data directly, they just link to it.

Comment: @Indolering Do they even do that now? Just looked at their website and it seems like they've moved on to providing analysis tools. Which makes my answer a bad one...

Comment: It is has fallen behind other priorities, but it's still a useful data source.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion the best option is [datahub.io](http://www.datahub.io) — it is run by the Open Knowledge Foundation ([okfn](https://okfn.org/)) and runs on The Comprehensive Kerbal Archive Network, [ckan](http://www.ckan.org/).

There's also github, which offers different options, but is still quite suitable.

I use both.

Comment: What are okfn and ckan? Please try to avoid acronyms without spelling them out.

Comment: those acronyms are their names. open knowledge foundation changed their name to okfn. that is what they go by. not sure what ckan stands for but it powers open source data repos, or rather, is the underlying code source. ckan stands for The Comprehensive Kerbal Archive Network (CKAN) http://ckan.org/ also https://okfn.org/

Comment: that may be exactly what I was looking for! Why doesn't this answer have more votes?